# Group action of a field $F$ on vector space $V$ is faithful.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-actions

I just want to see if this proof is correct. The only question relating to the exercise I'll be referencing is one that seems to correct a fault in the wording.

Exercise $7$ of Section $1.7$ of Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra book says, "Prove that in Example $2$ of this section, the group action is faithful.". Once this question's wording is corrected, this translates to the following:

Suppose $V$ is a non-trivial vector space over a field $F$. Show that the group action $\phi:\mathbb{F}^{\times}\times V\rightarrow V$ defined by $\phi(g,v)=gv$ is faithful.

Here's my attempt.

Suppose $g,h\in\mathbb{F}^{\times}$ such that $\sigma_g=\sigma_h$. That is, for any $v\in V$, $gv=hv$. Adding $-hv$ to both sides gives us $gv-hv=(g-h)v=\overline{0}$ where $\overline{0}$ is the zero vector. Since $V$ is non-trivial and this holds for any $v\in V$, it must be that $g-h=0$. Thus, $g=h$ and the permutation representation associated with $\phi$ is injective. Therefore, $\phi$ is faithful.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. PS: I know that the answer is "trivial", but when the question being is just asking for yes/no (+info why no), well the answer is that simple and it is OK to post it as such.

Comment: From the perspective of a questioner, I would also be very careful with these quick "answers written as comments", since often it means that the commenter has not invested enough time for a  good answer. For example, here a good answer would also ask to explain the step made in "Since $V$ is non-trivial, ..." in more detail, especially since this might as well be unclear to the OP (*I just want to see if this proof is correct* makes me **very** dubious), but surely essential to the argument.

Comment: Well how far do you have to go when explaining steps in a proof? V being non-trivial clearly means that there's a non-zero vector, so in order for (g-h)v to be the zero vector when v is a non-zero vector, g-h must be zero. That's not hard to realize, not hard enough to warrant putting it in the proof. It stems from simple linear algebra.

Comment: @XStanton What do you mean by $\sigma_g$? Do you mean $\sigma_g:V\to V$ is $v\mapsto \phi(g,v)=gv$?

Comment: $\sigma_g$ is the image of $g$ under the permutation representation.